# Prove using mathematical induction $1\cdot2+2\cdot2^2+3\cdot2^3+\ldots+n\cdot2^n=2[1+(n-1)2^n]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, induction, exponentiation

> Prove the result using [Mathematical Induction](https://ediscretestructures.blogspot.com/2022/03/principle-of-mathematical-induction.html) $$1\cdot2+2\cdot2^2+3\cdot2^3+\ldots\ldots+n\cdot2^n=2[1+(n-1)2^n].$$

I've been stuck on this problem for hours, I have no idea how do even calculate it. The exponents throw me off. If anyone can help me break it down step-by-step, I would truly appreciate it.

Here's my attempt
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your points $2$ and $3$, we need to show that

$$2(1+(k-1)2^k)+(k+1)2^{k+1}= 2(1+k2^{k+1})\\\stackrel{\text{divide by 2}}\iff 1+(k-1)2^k+(k+1)2^{k}= 1+k2^{k+1}\\\stackrel{\text{cancel out 1}}\iff  (k-1)2^k+(k+1)2^{k}= k2^{k+1}\\\stackrel{\text{divide by} \,2^k}\iff  (k-1)+(k+1)= 2k$$

Comment: Omg thank you very much!! this was very clear, i understand much better now. I appreciate the time you took to show me the steps

Comment: @DanielCorro You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Without induction it is rather simple problem.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n kx^k=x\sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k-1}=x\sum_{k=1}^n(x^k)'=x\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x^k\right)'=x\left(x\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right)'.$$ Now compute the derivative and put $x=2.$

Comment: Had you learned ([tag:derivatives]) when you were learning ([tag:induction])?  OP asks for clarification for his/her induction problem.  Although I appreciate your choice of function, I think OP can hardly apply similar techniques in exams.

Comment: My intention was to show certain technique. It is not bad to know more than one method. The advantage is one need not to know the form of the sum. It is directly computable.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The base case is fairly easy: $0\times\left(\ldots\right)=2\left(1+(0-1)\times2^0\right)$. If we assume that $\sum_{n=0}^k n2^{n}=2\left(1+(k-1)\cdot2^{k}\right)$, then our goal for the induction case is to prove that: $$
\underbrace{2\left(1+(k-1)\cdot2^{k}\right)}_{\sum_{n=0}^k {n2^{n}}}+ \underbrace{(k+1)2^{k+1}}_{\text{$(k+1)$'th term}}=2\left(1+k\cdot2^{k+1}\right)$$

Then, divide through by 2 and expand. Can you take it from here?

Comment: yeah i didnt know i had to bring out the 2 on both sides then divide, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mistake while doubling $2[1+(K-1)2^K]$.

To give a clearer and more concise presentation of the inductive step, I suggest writing one side at one row.

\begin{align}
& 2[1+(K-1)2^K] + (K+1) 2^{K+1} \\
&= 2 + (K-1) 2^{K+1} + (K+1) 2^{K+1} \\
&= 2 + 2K 2^{K+1} \\
&= 2[1 + K 2^{K+1}]
\end{align}